# Forced change on a select list

Tags: jquery

I would like to select an option into a select list and trigger the code into the change function.

PHP request code :

```
$la_reservation = $dbh->prepare("SELECT *,
                                          Date_debut, Date_fin, 
                                          client.Nom_societe, Personne_de_contact_idPersonne_de_contact,
                                          IdAdresse, adresse.Rue, adresse.Numero, adresse.Boite, adresse.Code_postal, adresse.Localite, adresse.Pays, adresse.Email, Tel1, adresse.Client_IdClient

                                          FROM bail 
                                          LEFT JOIN reservation ON idBail = Ref_bail
                                          LEFT JOIN client ON bail.Ref_filiale = client.IdClient
                                          LEFT JOIN personne_de_contact ON Personne_de_contact_idPersonne_de_contact = idPersonne_de_contact
                                          LEFT JOIN adresse ON adresse.Client_IdClient = client.IdClient
                                          WHERE idBail = :num_reservation");
            $data = array(":num_reservation"=>$_GET['num_res']);
            //echo str_replace(array_keys($data), array_values($data), $la_reservation->queryString);
            $la_reservation->execute($data);
            $res = $la_reservation->fetch();
```

I use $res['IdClient'] to indicate which option I want to select in the select list :

```
<script>$('#liste_clients').val("<?php echo $res['IdClient']?>");</script>
```

The generated code is :

```
<script>$('#liste_clients').val("14");</script>
```

but the alert in the change function is not working:

```
$("#liste_clients").change(function(){
alert("here");
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `.on()`  event, Since the data is  dynamically added into the page.

```
$(document).on("change", "#liste_clients", function(event){
    alert("changed");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#liste_clients option[value=14]').attr('selected', 'selected');
       $('#liste_clients').trigger('change');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your great reply.  This is a good solution to resolve this problem...